# What is the rock I found on the Delaware river yesterday?

Tags: geology, rivers

I spotted this large striped rock found on Delaware River. Note the fossil in the first picture. What kind of rock is this?

[image][image][image] [image]

Comment: Use this guide to improve your question: https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions/125#125

Answer (score 3):

The boulder appears to be dark grey  fossiliferous limestone or dolostone with softer tan layers which might be: limestone or calcareous claystone/siltstone/sandstone.
From the photo, the tan layers do not appear to be shale.

I have a hand specimen which is very similar from southern New Jersey.
It is harder grey limestone inter-layered with light tan calcareous siltstone.
[image]